# Creating/modifying arrowhead symbology to create a 'pie' style symbol around a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have a point dataset that has 18 (2 categories of 9) variables that need to be symbolized. We want to symbolize each variable using an arrowhead symbol or some kind of triangular symbol that, by adjusting angle and offset we can position around the center point, with each arrow head being a piece of a pie/pizza.

Below are some examples of how we have achieved similar outcomes with other datasets.

[image: This shows 8 different variables, across 2 categories (filled and hollow)]

The above is the affect we are trying to achieve, with the exception of wanting less white space between pieces, and 9 pieces in total. This model uses symbols from the ESRI dimensioning font in the character marker symbol type. However, you are not able to adjust the size/shape of the arrowhead symbol, so cannot reduce the white area.

Below is an example using the arrow marker symbol. This provides the ability to adjust the width and length of the arrowhead along with offset and angle. So it is possible to reduce the white area between pieces. However there is no ability to provide both hollow and filled symbology.

[image: This shows 8 variables using the arrowhead marker symbol]

So basically I need the best of each of these solutions, the ability to have both filled and hollow symbology, and the ability to adjust the size/shape, angle and offset of the arrowhead. Any suggestions welcome? Is it possible to easily create your own symbol? That could be the easiest way.

Just to note, the data does not allow the use of the actual pie chart symbology, hence why we are effectively making our own.

UPDATE- Attached image of representative data. If the number is greater or equal to one then is is represented with a pie piece. If it is 0 the pie piece is left out. Full pie pieces cover over hollow, so hollow will only show if full = 0 and hollow = 1 or more for the same variable/color.

[image: Representation of data table]

Comment: Your pictures show 8 categories

Comment: Are you already using one layer per "piece of pie"?  If not, I think that would be my starting point.  I don't think you have described your data sufficiently yet.  I recommend that you show one row from your point feature class and what its symbology should look like.  In particular I think you need to expand upon how you need to hollow out some of the "pieces of pie".

Comment: It isn't clear from your post what processes/tools you have used to produce the results you have so far, so hard to to give advice. The instructions for creating new symbols of your own are at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_creating_new_symbols/00s600000004000000/  down about halfway.  Creating new symbols is not an easy process because of the tiny scale you are working at.  Plus you are going to have to coordinate all your different little triangles.  If you want to try to create vector symbols, that is an additional process.

Comment: Also, have you looked at cartographic representations?

Comment: Yes, each pie piece is a separate layer. So this data is represented in the map 9 times, with each of the 9 layers having a unique definition query to represent the relevant variable, eg; 'GREEN_FULL > 0'. I have updated the question with an attached image of a mock-up of the data table for reference.